# Play background music and sound effect at the same time

Tags: jquery, xcode, ipad, html

I have a game where I need background music playing and when I click a button it should play a sound.  It plays the sound but stops the music.

The only way to turn the music back on is to have another event such as a button click.  Is there any way to play a sound while the background music continues to play?

This is my code so far.

```
var a = new Audio("Latin Groove Hype App.mp3");

function init()
{  
    playBackGroundLoop();

}// in html(<body onload = "init()">)


function playSoundEffect()
{
    var playSoundCorrect = new Audio("Correct synth.mp3");
    playSoundCorrect.play();
}


function playBackGroundLoop()
{
    a.addEventListener('ended', function() 
                   {
                       this.currentTime = 0;
                       this.play();//plays music on loop
                   }, true);
    a.play();
}

$(function()
  {
  $("#playButton").on("click",function()
                {
                 playSoundEffect();
                }
  });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a minute and pass my script to fit your project:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id=nav>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio-nav">
    <source src="click.mp3"></source>
    <source src="click.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>
<audio id="audio-bg">
    <source src="bg.mp3"></source>
    <source src="bg.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>

<a id="toggle" href="javascript:;">PLAY/PAUSE</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var bgMusic = $('#audio-bg')[0],
    navMusic = $('#audio-nav')[0],
    playing = true;

bgMusic.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    if (playing) {
        this.play();
    }
}, false);

bgMusic.play();

$('#toggle').click(function() {
    if (!bgMusic.paused) {
        bgMusic.pause();
        playing = false;
    } else {
        bgMusic.play();
        playing = true;
    }
});

$('#nav a').click(function() {
    navMusic.play();
});​
```

...and here, a fully [functional demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/HnMe9/)